# Can we load an angular app inside a dom element?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular10

- I have two web apps. The first one is a normal javascript web app, and the other is angular(Version 10).
- After loading the javascript app, I want to load the angular app inside a DIV.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: Seems like a similar question has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238976/how-to-include-an-angular-app-dynamically-into-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use an iframe and point it to a folder of your application that have the compiled angular app files.

First step : save your compiled angular files inside a folder 'angular' for example in the same level of your html file.
Second step : put the iframe in the HTML and make reference to that folder '/angular' in the src property.

More about iframes here : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.ASP

Comment: How can this be done? Show some code snippet with an example code. Your answer cannot be salvaged from our end so I recommeded its deletion.